# RTK-Query - not able to re-fetch after service api return error when conditional fetching with skipToken

Tags: redux, rtk-query

Trying to do a conditional fetch when a button click event, it works with the skipToken as mentioned in doc.  However, when service return error (ex: 404), fetch wouldn't fire again.

Thinking it may be cache is preventing it to re-fetch so update the conditional skipToken with a count.

```
let [count, setCount] = useState(undefined);
const { data } = useUsersQuery(count ?? skipToken);

const getUsers = () => {
setCount(counter++);
}
.
.
<button onClick={() => getUsers()}>get users</button>
```

this work but created unnecessary data in redux store.  There must be a better way??
may be invalidate the error cache? if that is the case how to invalidate? or some sort of force fetch when click again?

also already set refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true in endpoints.

kind of new to the RTK query, appreciate any pointers.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a query in response to a button being clicked then it seems like you really want to use a lazy query. The normal queries run once on the initial render and if their cache tags are invalidated, whereas the lazy queries return a trigger function to be called when you want to execute the query.

See [useLazyQuery](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#uselazyquery)

Example:

```
const [getUsers, { data }] = useLazyUsersQuery();

...

<button type="button" onClick={getUsers}>
  get users
</button>
```

Just FYI, the regular query hook also returns a `refetch` function to force refetch the query.

```
const { data, refetch } = useUsersQuery();

...

<button onClick={refetch}>get users</button>
```